# Can't print 9x9 table correctly

Tags: php, html, html-table

The code is giving first 10 numbers in first row and 9 numbers in other 7 rows and 8 numbers in last row.

How can I obtain the 9x9 matrix so that all the rows have 9 numbers?

I have tried everything, but nothing works. Is there any way to do this?

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
    <?php

        for ($i = 1; $i < 82; $i++) {
            $arr[] = $i;
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i < 81; $i++) {
            echo '<td>' . $arr[$i] . '</td>';

        if ($i % 9 == 0 && $i != 0) {
            echo "</tr><tr>";
        }


        }

    ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The best is what `@Rizier` says, but if you want to modify only your code then:-**

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
    <?php
    for ($i = 1; $i < 82; $i++) {
    $arr[] = $i;
}
    $j=1; //add a new count starts from 1
    for ($i=0; $i<81; $i++)
    {
        echo '<td>'.$arr[$i].'</td>';

        if ($j%9==0)  // check counter modules 9 will be zero or not. it will break after each 9 iteration.
        {
           echo "</tr><tr>";
        }


    $j++;} // increase the value of counter
    ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Output:-http://prntscr.com/7bu34m

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

Here I first create an array with 81 elements with [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php). Then I [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) the array into a 2-dimensional array, where each sub array has 9 elements.

At the end just loop through all sub array and [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) them into one single row.

```
<table border=1>
<?php

    $arr = range(1, 81);
    $arr = array_chunk($arr, 9);

    foreach($arr as $v)
        echo "<tr><td>" . implode("</td><td>", $v) . "</td></tr>";

?>
</table>
```

output:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27
28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45
46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54
55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63
64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72
73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81
```

Answer (score 0):

you are starting the `$i=0;` so the first condition was true it was placed the `</tr>` after first result

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
    <?php
    for ($i = 1; $i < 82; $i++) {
    $arr[] = $i;
}
    $j=1;
    for ($i=0; $i<81; $i++)
    {
        echo '<td>'.$arr[$i].'</td>';

        if ($j%9==0) 
        {
           echo "</tr><tr>";
        }


    $j++;}
    ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

output

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27
28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45
46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54
55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63
64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72
73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for ($i=1; $i<=81; $i++)
{
    echo '<td>'.$arr[$i].'</td>';

    if ($i%9==0 && $i!=1) 
    {
       echo "</tr><tr>";
    }


}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost current ... Please  echo ''.$arr[$i].''; line below the if condition like this...

```
<table border=1>
<tr>
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i < 82; $i++) {
    $arr[] = $i;
}
for ($i=0; $i<81; $i++)
{

    if ($i%9==0 && $i!=0) 
    {
       echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
    echo '<td>'.$arr[$i].'</td>';



}
?>
</tr>
</table>
```